# Bitbake: How to only fetch the sources?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

There is a project in which we use project yocto, and our metas fetch source from some remote git repositories.

The problem is that these repositories are only accessible in some particular situations/specific times.

Therefore, I need a way to fetch the repos (when they are available), as to have them locally, but not build anything at that time.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Starting from Yocto 2.5, it has changed:

```
 bitbake <target> --runall=fetch
```

Previously it was:

```
bitbake <target> -c fetchall
```

[Bitbake Usage-and-syntax](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5.1/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#usage-and-syntax)

Comment: That is what I was afraid off :) Also, Yocto 2.5 is confusing, see this table to work out when the change occurred: https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Releases

Answer (score 2):

Try `bitbake -c fetchall <target>`

It might help to add:

```
BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS = "1"
```

to local.conf, which generates tarballs for all fetched sources which aren't already an archive.

Answer (score 0):

```
bitbake <target> --runonly=fetch
```

according to [#usage-and-syntax](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/2.5.1/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#usage-and-syntax)
But bitbake doesn't give a bit of reaction on this option, just performing all steps (patch, compile, install). Bitbake knows better what to do, uhhh...

Comment: bitbake <target> --runall=fetch